# Custom Expand/Collapse image of WinForms TreeView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

Is there any possibility of changing the default expand\collapse image (+\-) of the .NET WinForms TreeView control?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566643/change-treenode-image-on-expand-collapse-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlikely. WinForms is notoriously un-customizable. Your best bet is to try to make the switch to WPF.